# Virtual CListCtrl Auto Size

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, autosize, clistctrl

I want to resize the columns of a virtual ClistCtrl (LVS_OWNERDATA flag) automatically.

I found in some forums that virtual lists can not use the "LVSCW_AUTOSIZE" option. Some suggest to implement an algorithm instead.

But once loaded my ClistCtrl without any resize option, a double-click on the header divider correctly resizes the visible columns.

So, how I can perform the function that is called by "HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW"?

Answer (score 1):

The autosizing suggested by Clements works for normal list controls, but not for virtual ones (because the control doesn't know anything about the column data). You have to provide the data column width yourself.

Comment: exactly! autosize doesn't work for a virtual list. but a double-click on the header divider does the task, even in a virtual list. So, there is a function who knows the size of column data even of a virtual list. My question is about that function.

Answer (score -1):

From [this Codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11483/Let-Your-ListCtrl-Adjust-its-Column-Widths-Automat), you should be able to autosize a column with something like:

```
pListCtrl->SetColumnWidth(i, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE);
int nColumnWidth = pListCtrl->GetColumnWidth(i);
pListCtrl->SetColumnWidth(i, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER);
int nHeaderWidth = pListCtrl->GetColumnWidth(i); 
pListCtrl->SetColumnWidth(i, max(nColumnWidth, nHeaderWidth));
```

You may need to handle [the LVN_GETDISPINFO notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to provide the necessary data to the virtual list control, though...

Comment: Autosize doesn't work with virtual lists. But a double-click on the header divider does the task even with a virtual list. Then a function like "autosize" (that works with virtual lists) exists somewhere. My question is about that function.